# How to reuse a Array variable in C using pointers

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, programming-languages

I need to answer this question testing this:

> Exercise 19-16: Fix the code in example so that the sample variable's value is saved before the while loop runs and is then restored afterward. Add a puts(sample) statement to the code after the while loop is done executing, to prove that the variable's original address is restored.

```
**Example:**
     #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char *sample = "From whence cometh my help?\n";

        while(putchar(*sample++))
            ;
        return(0);
    }
```

I want to check if my answer is correct, may be you can give an explanation, because I have no clear understanding about pointers and variables. 
And this is my answer:

```
     #include <stdio.h>

        int main()
        {
            char *sample = "From whence cometh my help?\n"; //This is my string
            char StringSample[31];
            int index = 0;

            while(sample[index] != '\0') //while the char is NOT equal to empty char (the last one)
            {
                index++; //increase the index by 1
                StringSample[index] = sample[index]; //put the char "n" inside the stringSample //
                putchar(*sample++);  //write it to the screen
            }
            putchar('\n'); //A new line

            //to put the entire string on screen again
            for (index=0; index<60; index++)
            {
                putchar(StringSample[index]); 
            }
            return(0);
        }
```

Here is my output:

[image]

I don't know why the string is split it to `From whence co` and why the rest of the text, that as you can see, has no sense.

I'm using Xcode 5.02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reference your `sample` variable as indexed as well as pointer . This will lead you to the wrong result.

```
while(sample[index] != '\0')   
{
    index++;
    StringSample[index] = sample[index];  // indexed access
    putchar(*sample++);                   // incrementing pointer sample. 
}
```

You can simply achieve your goal as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *sample = "From whence cometh my help?\n";
    char *ptr = sample;  // Saving the value of sample

     while(putchar(*sample++))
        ;
    putchar('\n');

    sample = ptr;        // Restoring sample's value.
    puts(sample);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char StringSample[31];
....
for (index=0; index<60; index++)
{
    putchar(StringSample[index]);
}
```

Your array has 31 cells, but you iterate far away till 60. God knows what you may access.

Answer (score 1):

You made this way more complicated that it needed to be.  Just save the pointer in another variable and copy it back when you're done.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *sample = "From whence cometh my help?\n";
    char *temp = sample;

    while(putchar(*sample++))
        ;

    sample = temp;
    puts(sample);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
From whence cometh my help?
From whence cometh my help?
```